# Chrome DevTools not find elements not search

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

I am using selenium for chrome automation.
for a while now the DevTool of chrome (F12) not working as expcted. (Version 84.0.4147.89 (Official Build) (64-bit))

When I try to locate element it is not find it even the element exists.
Even when I press ctrl + f and search for a big word it is not find it.
I need the dev tool since it is mark where the element, and where I am standing. Is their any soloution?
I provide two pics: in one it's find and marked the value, and after I add the letter 'c' it is not find. Moreover it says found one and it is the search field, what happened to chrome?   and all the locators not found as well
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The real issue is [DevTools within Google Chrome 84.0](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/05/devtools) doesn't highlights the first matched element.

Incase, it's a single match, the search result does show `1 of 1` but the element is not highlighted within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes)

As an example, we all are aware that the search box on [*Google Home Page*](https://www.google.com/) can be identified uniquely using the [css-selector](/questions/tagged/css-selector):

```
[name='q']
```

DevTools within Google Chrome 84.0, does finds the element and shows `1 of 1` but the element is not highlighted.

[image: snapshot]

However, if there are multiple element matching to the [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890), barring the first matched element, the other elements are highlighted.

Comment: what is the logic? if it is unique why not to mark it? how can I know where it is located in the DOM? I have a page so I need to find it in F12 and than copy the page to notepad++ and find it?

Comment: It's a bug in Chrome 84, officially once triaged I will share with you the  details. I'm waiting for the CA guys triage the issue.