# How to locate a div with non unique id/class, which contains a div with a certain text and then fetch all the <td> and <tr> tags under that div

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, xpath-1.0

So I have HTML something like this.

```
<div class="generic classname" id="generic ID name" >  // div1
<div class="presentation" id="body presentation">      // div2
<font>unique text</font>
<div class= "generic classname" id="generic ID name""> //div3
// under this div I have the table entry.
// multiple <td> and <tr>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

My job is to match the "unique text" in div no 2, so I can locate the element div number 1 and then fetch all the table   in div no 3

The problem is I am not sure how to locate the **div which doesn't have a unique class name or id name**. I can't use full XPath, since the table changes and the divs change randomly.

Comment: _so I can locate the element div number 1 and then_ Why do you want to venture into `div1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the HTML:

```
<div class="generic classname" id="generic ID name" >  // div1
    <div class="presentation" id="body presentation">      // div2
        <font>unique text</font>
        <div class= "generic classname" id="generic ID name"> //div3
            // under this div I have the table entry.
            // multiple <td> and <tr>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As your usecase is not dependent on any of the `<div1>` attributes, you can easily avoid considering `<div1>`.

---

### Solution

To locate the third `<div>` you have four approaches as follows:

- Using the text `unique text` and `<div> attributes`:

  ```
  //font[text()='unique text']//following::div[@class='generic classname' and @id='generic ID name']
  ```
- Using the text`unique text` and *index*:

  ```
  //font[text()='unique text']//following::div[1]
  ```
- Using the `<div2>` which have a child `<font>` tag with text as `unique text` and `<div> attributes`:

  ```
  //div[./font[text()='unique text']]//following-sibling::div[@class='generic classname' and @id='generic ID name']
  ```
- Using the `<div2>` which have a child `<font>` tag with text as `unique text` and *index*:

  ```
  //div[./font[text()='unique text']]//following-sibling::div[1]
  ```

Comment: One more question I also encountered a case where the <div2> tag has another <div> tag with 'unique text'. so div2 has a child div which has the text. the table is located on the same level as div2. How would I then locate the table?

Comment: @BountyCollector _...<div2> tag has another <div> tag with 'unique text'..._ but we are considering the `<font>` tag in the first and second option with 'unique text'. So IMO, this still should work.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I just tested it for both cases and it seems to work flawlessly. I am pretty new to this stuff, do you have a resource recommendation?

Comment: @BountyCollector Pickup any _xpath_ documentation and validate them within any website through [tag:google-chrome-devtools]. See the discussions: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62945647/why-xpath-does-not-highlighted-the-yellow-mark-in-chrome84/63073849#63073849), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62960908/chrome-84-inspect-element-find-results-not-highlighted-in-yellow-like-before/63075040#63075040) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63034593/chrome-devtools-not-find-elements-not-search/63035359#63035359)

Answer (score 1):

Use the below `xpath` with reference to `div 2` to find the unique text and then find div and table inside div.

```
//div[./font[text()='unique text']]/div[1]/table
```

Answer (score 1):

If all your divs are nested as you say and your aim is to get the table in div3, you don't need to get the parent.

This is one option:

```
//font[text()='unique text']/following-sibling::div
```

This xpath finds the `font` with your unique text then it's sibling (same parent) `div`

This xpath identifier is another option:

```
//font[text()='unique text']/parent::*/div
```

this xpath finds the `font` with your unique text then get it's `*` (any) parent then gets the relevant div inside it.

You can do the parent axes to up again if you want "div1".

Looks like this in devtools:
[image: devtool single match]

This is based on your html looking like:

```
<div class="generic classname" id="generic ID name" >
    <div class="presentation" id="body presentation">
        <font>unique text</font>
        <div class="generic classname" id="generic ID name""> 
            // under this div I have the table entry.
            // multiple <td> and <tr>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Different HTML would need a different xpath so please say if you need to update.

Answer (score 0):

I would search or get the tag of the "unique text" with js.

```js
<script>
  // get the element
  let elem = document.getElementsByName('font');
</script>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp

Answer (score -1):

One more option for you:

```
//div[font='unique text']/div
```